# Inner property data binding issue

Tags: angular

When rendering data out onto a template where the data is coming from an api, I've noticed you have to use a question mark if the data is in a nested object/array.

ie:

```
approveBooking?.cabBooking?.bookingId
```

instead of just:

```
approveBooking.cabBooking.bookingId
```

Is this the correct way of approaching this? Does using typescript interfaces circumvent having to use "?" because you're telling the app upfront what nested objects/arrays will be in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths

`?` in Angular is safe navigation operator which just avoids the falsy and null values check in your template data binding.

Offcourse you could do the same with typescript interfaces but this is shortcut way to check for flasy and null values check.

Comment: Cool thanks, do you personally use the ? in the template route, or do you put them in the interface?

Comment: Yes, I massively use `?` in template binding , I am not big fan if interface though

Answer (score 1):

Actually the reason why ? is used is to persist the data to be displayed only when it is available..

lets take for instance you are pulling this data off a JSON object from an api request, not using the ? displays an error when the variables load, since the page loads immediately and renders the values to Null when the api services delays, but the " ? " operator allows the data to be available before displaying it.

in your case then,

```
approveBooking?.cabBooking?.bookingId
```

this tells the application to

1. display bookingId property when cabBooking Object is available, and
2. load cabBooking property when the approveBooking Object is available.

i hope this answers it.

Answer (score 1):

> There are two ways of safe navigation -

1) **using `?`:** As you already did -

```
approveBooking?.cabBooking?.bookingId
```

2) **using ['']:** You could also use safe traversal as -

```
approveBooking['cabBooking']['bookingId']
```

---

***Why use safe navigation?***
*It is used to avoid sequential explicit null checks and assignments and replace them with method/property chaining. In programming languages where the navigation operator (e.g. ".") leads to an error if applied to a null object, the safe navigation operator stops the evaluation of a method/field chain and returns null as the value of the chain expression.* Refer **[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator)** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

"?" work as a ternary operator. It is only work on angular template engine,it is not a typescript or javascript feature.

Eg: suppose in your api call, response object has couple of fields which are not there for always, I mean whenever you call that API.

1st case:

```
response = {
    uname: 'xyz',
    country: {
        iso: 'IN',
        name: 'India',
        ...
    },
    ssn: 2839483
}
```

2nd case:

```
response = {
    uname: 'abc',
    ssn: 8765678
}
```

In your template you want to use conditions `*ngIf` to check whether the user from a specific country by iso value so that you can display a flag for it.

Now, for first case when you this `response.country.iso` it gives error in your console, saying can not find iso of undefined. To safely handle this thing in your dynamic templating, you need to write `response.country?.iso`

Notice I m only using '`?`' operator for country field, as I know this field is only variable in my API response data.